Issue with Writing DXF File from Shapefile Using Terra in R
Problem
I am trying to write a DXF file of AutoCAD from the terra package. According to the documentation, this should be possible.
Load Packages
library(terra)
#;-) terra 1.7.71

Check Available Drivers
I checked the available drivers to confirm that DXF is supported:
The reason I think this is true is that if I show this data frame:
DF <- terra::gdal(drivers =T)
DF <- DF[DF$name == "DXF",]
knitr::kable(DF)





name
type
can
vsi
long.name




161
DXF
vector
read/write
TRUE
AutoCAD DXF



The output indicates that terra should be able to read and write DXF files.
Data Preparation
Here is a minimal example where I read a shapefile and select a single column:
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v <- v["NAME_2"]

Attempt to Write DXF
However, when I try to write it to a DXF file, I get an error and an empty file is created:
terra::writeVector(v, "Test.DXF", filetype = "DXF", overwrite = TRUE)
#;-) Warning: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'NAME_2'
#;-) not created. (GDAL error 1)
#;-) Error: [writeVector] Field creation failed for: NAME_2

Here you can see that the created file is empty
terra::vect("Test.DXF")
#;-)  class       : SpatVector 
#;-)  geometry    : none 
#;-)  dimensions  : 0, 0  (geometries, attributes)
#;-)  extent      : 0, 0, 0, 0  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#;-)  source      : Test.DXF (entities)
#;-)  coord. ref. :

Session info


Standard output and standard error

✖ Install the styler package in order to use `style = TRUE`.




Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#;-) ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#;-)  setting  value
#;-)  version  R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
#;-)  os       Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
#;-)  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#;-)  ui       X11
#;-)  language en_US:en
#;-)  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#;-)  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#;-)  tz       Europe/Copenhagen
#;-)  date     2024-05-27
#;-)  pandoc   2.19.2 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#;-) 
#;-) ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#;-)  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#;-)  cli           3.6.2   2023-12-11 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  codetools     0.2-19  2023-02-01 [4] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#;-)  digest        0.6.35  2024-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  evaluate      0.23    2023-11-01 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  fastmap       1.2.0   2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  fs            1.6.4   2024-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  glue          1.7.0   2024-01-09 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  htmltools     0.5.8.1 2024-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  knitr         1.46    2024-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  lifecycle     1.0.4   2023-11-07 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  Rcpp          1.0.12  2024-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  reprex        2.1.0   2024-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  rlang         1.1.3   2024-01-10 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  rmarkdown     2.27    2024-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  rstudioapi    0.16.0  2024-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [3] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#;-)  terra       * 1.7-71  2024-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  withr         3.0.0   2024-01-16 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  xfun          0.44    2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  yaml          2.3.8   2023-12-11 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-) 
#;-)  [1] /home/au687614/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4
#;-)  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#;-)  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#;-)  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#;-) 
#;-) ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


I do not know if this is helpful but one can do:
values(v) <- NULL
terra::writeVector(v, "Test.DXF", filetype = "DXF", overwrite = TRUE)
x <- vect("Test.DXF")
x
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : Test.DXF (entities)
# coord. ref. :  
# names       : Layer PaperSpace       SubClasses Linetype EntityHandle  Text
# type        : <chr>  <logical>            <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr>
# values      :     0       <NA> AcDbEntity:AcDb~       NA        20000 SOLID
#                   0       <NA> AcDbEntity:AcDb~       NA        20001 SOLID
#                   0       <NA> AcDbEntity:AcDb~       NA        20002 SOLID


Hi @robert it helps a lot, can you think of any way on how I could add one of the features in it, I tried this after what you did:
x <- vect("Test.DXF")

Test2 <- terra::vect(f) 
x$Text <- Test2$NAME_2

terra::writeVector(x, "Test2.DXF", filetype = "DXF", overwrite = TRUE)

But it keeps the same text SOLID
